# Is it possible to realize multiple actions with FB Open Graph?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I've gone through the introduction of the new graph options. I'm not a developer, but a marketer and I need to present to my superiors what can be done with the graph.

I don't understand one thing: If I, for example, have a `"Cook"` button, and the user presses it, Is it possible to have two actions at the same time:

```
 1. publish to user's feed (or ticker)
 2. proceed to a page on my website?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have both actions (post to Graph and redirect user to new content) on a single client side click of an HTML element.  You do that both clientside or from a server.